# What are the most effective R packages for classification problems?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Let's say we have data of the following form: a categorical response $y$ and covariates $x_1,x_2,...,x_p$ that can be either categorical or continuous (a very common scenario). Further, let's say the covariates are noisy, and there are a lot of them (high dimensionality).

What machine learning / R-packages are surprisingly effective/robust at solving this kind of problem? I find randomForest to be surprisingly effective in that it handles noise and high-dimensionality very well. What other techniques/packages are there with this property.

I know this question may seem to be opinionated. But I am just asking based on *your* experience what technique/package have you found that handles high noise and dimensionality robustly? This can be useful to everyone looking to try out new techniques and packages (and also, I believe that is where a lot of the power of R comes from).

Comment: This question is off-topic as currently framed, both because it is `too broad` and because it is `primarily opinion based`. Please review our [materials](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for forming appropriate questions on CV.

Comment: Hey gung, I understand, I will try to rephrase, but I think this thread can be helpful to everyone. Most people have their favorite package that works surprisingly well, and I have not been able to find any good threads on this.

Answer (score 2):

I've often found the [GBM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html) to be a good improvement on the [randomForest package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html). For linear models, [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) is surprisingly effective.

[caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) is an awesome way to try many different models and compare them on the same cross-validation folds.

Comment: So wait, caret contains functions that let you specify other functions from different R packages, and let's you compare all of those other functions? That sounds fantastic if that is case! And here I was thinking about building something like that my self

Comment: @dlaser.  It sure does.  It's got a great API-- rather than building something yourself, you should submit patches to caret!